# CopyToDataTable method

Tags: c#, linq

I've been looking at the following tutorial on MSDN, but can't seem to apply the method to my code- cannot figure out what the difference is!

The article, is at [Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx), with code in particular-

```
// Create a sequence. 
Item[] items = new Item[] { 
  new Book{Id = 1, Price = 13.50, Genre = "Comedy", Author = "Gustavo Achong"}, 
  new Book{Id = 2, Price = 8.50, Genre = "Drama", Author = "Jessie Zeng"},
  new Movie{Id = 1, Price = 22.99, Genre = "Comedy", Director = "Mary Barnes"},
  new Movie{Id = 1, Price = 13.40, Genre = "Action", Director = "Emmanuel Black"}
};

// Query for items with price greater than 9.99.
var query = from i in items
             where i.Price > 9.99
             orderby i.Price
             select i;

// Load the query results into new DataTable.
DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Seems simple enough.  Object array with subclasses of book and movie, seems to be convertible to DataRow, which is what CopyToDataTable runs off.

But my object array, which I store in a var, doesn't allow me to use the CopyToDataTable method.  I would have thought my object 'qryData' is very similar to the above 'items'....

```
var qryData =
    sdTable.AsEnumerable().Cast<DataRow>()
           .OrderByDescending(t => t[c.ColumnName] == DBNull.Value
                                    ? 0 : Convert.ToSingle(t[c.ColumnName]))
           .GroupBy(t => t["DAT_ID"])
           .Select(g => new {g, count = g.Count()})
           .SelectMany(x => x.g.Select(b => b)
                                .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, x.count), (j, i) => new {
                                   inst = j["DAT_ID"],
                                   idn = j["ID_NUM"],
                                   val = j[c.ColumnName],
                                   tdt = dailyCount[Convert.ToInt32(j["DAT_ID"])],
                                   rn = i
                                 })
             );
```

Query works fine, comes back with big collection of '(inst,idn,val,tdt,rn)', but can't use CopyToDataTable on it. {method is not available}  Adding a .ToArray() or .AsEnumerable() doesn't help either.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

Quick note,
I have included System.Data, thinking that the .CopyToDataTable() method was available in that.  I tried to include System.Data.DataTableExtensions - but not there.  Then I tried to include System.Data.DataSetExtensions as a (.NET) reference in my project -- but hasn't helped.

Comment: Do you have a `using` statement for System.Data.DataTableExtensions?

Comment: So what happens when you try to use it?  Do you get an error, or an exception at runtime?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I tried to do a include System.Data.DataTableExtensions, but the namespace wasn't found

Answer (score 0):

Based on this statement:

> but can't use CopyToDataTable on it. Adding a .ToArray() or .AsEnumerable() doesn't help either.

you just need to add the appropriate `using` statement to the top of your code file to use the `namespace` the extension method is defined in. So, check out the `namespace` you defined that class in and add that `using` to the top of the code file you want to use it in.

Comment: @willy_pond, so you built the extension method and it's housed in a `namespace System.Data` declaration?

Comment: hi, I believe that it is in the "System.Data" namespace, which I am including.  just to be sure I tried to do a include System.Data.DataTableExtensions, but the namespace wasn't found

Comment: I haven't built any extension method - I thought the .CopyToDataTable() extension method was available in System.Data - it is certainly spoken about on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx